# Redhat init script on startup

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat, svn, init.d

I installed Redhat 6.4 and created a new init script which updates a project using SVN.

I then configured the script in chkconfig.
The problem is everytime i restart the server i lose ssh connectivity for some reason (connection refused after the restart), and i have to restore the HD from snapshot.

The server is located on EC2 with a key file, maybe it's got something to do with permissions?

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to [look at the console output upon reboot](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/622).

It's likely that sshd is just not starting.

Also, sounds like your init script could be broken.

If  your script is hanging and it is being started before ssh, you won't have access to the machine. You may consider [making sure your custom init script boots last](https://serverfault.com/questions/176055/how-to-change-linux-services-startup-boot-order).

Answer (score 1):

init scripts are used for starting/stopping system services and updating a project using SVN doesn't sound like a system service.
  I would suggest other approaches:
1. if you need to make the update only at boot time, launch your script from /etc/rc.d/rc.local
2. if you need to make the update periodically, then set the script to be run from cron