# how to change the startup order of linux init scripts in Redhat, Centos

Tags: linux, centos, debian, redhat, sles

From this changing  [How to change Linux services startup/boot order?](https://serverfault.com/questions/176055/how-to-change-linux-services-startup-boot-order) changing the values of the symbolic links it is evident that startup order is changed.

In debian derivatives we use

> update-rc.d apache2 defaults 20 80

Do we have similar command in Centos/Redhat and ?

if so what it is ?

and what should be possible changes in init scripts header ?

Note: I should use init system (not any systemd or upstart)

Comment: Which versions of the named OS are you referring to, it's important?

Comment: @Lain Centos 6.5  is the current version

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative will be to change the line starting with `# chkconfig:` in the service init script directly. This is explained in the [chkconfig(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chkconfig) man page.

> **Runlevel Files**
>
> Each service which should be manageable by chkconfig needs two or more
>   commented lines added to its init.d script. The first line tells
>   chkconfig what runlevels the service should be started in by default,
>   as well as the start and stop priority levels. If the service should
>   not, by default, be started in any runlevels, a - should be used in
>   place of the runlevels list. The second line contains a description
>   for the service, and may be extended across multiple lines with
>   backslash continuation.
>
> For example, random.init has these three lines:
>
> ```
> # chkconfig: 2345 20 80
> # description: Saves and restores system entropy pool for \
> #              higher quality random number generation.
> ```
>
> This says that the random script should be started in levels 2, 3, 4,
>   and 5, that its start priority should be 20, and that its stop
>   priority should be 80. You should be able to figure out what the
>   description says; the \ causes the line to be continued. The extra
>   space in front of the line is ignored.

After changing the script, if you will need to run the `chkconfig` command (as root) with the `reset` option for that service.  With "reset", chkconfig will automatically create start/stop symlinks in the configured run levels with given priorities.

Comment: Thanks for info, I was wondering can I use CHKCONFIG with Default-start and Default-stop

Comment: I don't think that will be possible.

Comment: +1 for the chkconfig reset command -- crucial.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually rename symlinks in your /etc/rcX.d directories to change boot order.

UPD: Under RHEL / CentOS you use command called ntsysv or chkconfig.

Comment: I know changing the symlinks  works, but would like to know is there any other alternative

Answer (score 0):

I would like add more details to above answer

in order to start the scrips especially in centos there is no such alternative like

```
update-rc.d
```

in Debain ,

Easiest way is to change the scripts [manually](https://serverfault.com/questions/176055/how-to-change-linux-services-startup-boot-order) as described here 
and e.g. code from /etc/init.d/postfix

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# postfix      Postfix Mail Transfer Agent
#
# chkconfig: 2345 80 30
# description: Postfix is a Mail Transport Agent, which is the program \
#              that moves mail from one machine to another.
# processname: master
# pidfile: /var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid
# config: /etc/postfix/main.cf
# config: /etc/postfix/master.cf
#
# Based on startup script from Simon J Mudd <sjmudd@pobox.com>
# 25/02/99: Mostly s/sendmail/postfix/g by John A. Martin <jam@jamux.com>
# 23/11/00: Changes & suggestions by Ajay Ramaswamy <ajayr@bigfoot.com>
# 20/01/01: Changes to fall in line with RedHat 7.0 style
# 23/02/01: Fix a few untidy problems with help from Daniel Roesen.

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: postfix MTA
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network $remote_fs
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $network $remote_fs
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: start and stop postfix
# Description: Postfix is a Mail Transport Agent, which is the program that
#              moves mail from one machine to another.
### END INIT INFO
```